# Natural language Generator using Data from table

Tags: deep-learning, data-science-model, nlp

I am working on some natural language generator part.

eg.1
Input to it will be

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A      B    13
X      Y    14
```

Output should be two sentence, one for each row

Number of columns and rows can change every time.
Please can any one suggest any approach/free source lib for it